# Запись javascript функции внутри функции

Tags: javascript

Есть такой код:

```
var f = function() {
    this.x = 5;
    (function() {
        this.x = 3;
    })();
    console.log(this.x);
}
```

Почему функция внутри функции записывается таким образом:

```
(function() {
    this.x = 3;
})();
```

А почему нельзя написать так:

```
function() {
    this.x = 3;
}
```

?

Comment: ой как все плохо, а где вы такой код нашли?

Comment: Grundy, в хабре нашел такой код. Вот источник: https://habrahabr.ru/post/149516/

Comment: Alexey Ten, мой вопрос не очень похож на то, что скинули источником.
Т.е. во-первых не дубликат, а во вторых ответы не устраивают.

Comment: @Ilnyr, нет, в данной редакции ваш вопрос абсолютный дубликат того, который предоставлен по ссылке. Если вопрос подразумевал что-то еще, стоит это добавить

Comment: @Ilnyr, кроме того, в приведенной статье вполне себе объясняется, что именно значит данный вызов

Comment: Это да, но у меня же содержит ключевое слово this. Это разве не разные вещи? А в этом источнике что-то не вижу упоминании про this в "обертке"

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42158/discussion-between-grundy-and-ilnyr).

Answer (score -2):

Это называется "обертка", вы объявляете функцию и сразу её вызываете.
Во втором случае пришлось-бы писать так:

```
var f1=function(_this) {
    _this.x = 3;
}
f1(this);
```

Смысл в том, что в "обертке" this принимает не значение самой функции, а значение внешней фунции.

Comment: почему так пришлось бы писать во втором случае? откуда появился параметр?

Comment: что значит _в "обертке" this принимает не значение самой функции, а значение внешней фунции._?

Comment: Да, тоже интересует подробности насчет последнего абзаца

Comment: это значит, что обертка использует this родительской области видимости.

Comment: @iKest, код приведенный в ответе не аналогичен тому, что приведен в вопросе

Comment: Не, ну с вопросом-то всё ясно. function() {
    this.x = 3;
}  - и дальше что? Фунцию объявили. И как её вызвать? Никак. Обертка (function() {...})() понятно что позволяет сразу вызывать анонимные функции, в callback'ах вообще шикарно. Но я по дурости всегда this пробрасывал внутрь функций. Правда я стараюсь только прототипированные объекты делать. Даже от call/bind  в пользу проброса this отказывался. Оказывается вообще контекст не понимаю. Минус 100 в карму и голову пеплом.